# PHP syntax error could not be converted to string?

Tags: php

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I have no idea what error is it and I am new in PHP.It is telling me error **in echo that line.**

```
   <?php foreach ($results as $value):
    echo '<div class="database">"'.$value.'"</div>' ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `$value` is an object. where is `$results` coming from? json_decode?

Comment: @Jamysim did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$value` is object. So you should not echo it directly. You can echo its attribute.

So, suppose it has `firstname` as attribute, then echo it like

```
echo '<div class="database">"'.$value->firstname.'"</div>' ?>
```

Or if you want to see what attributes the object has, then you may first print it

```
print_r($value);die';
```